# Setting a custom TTF Font in mPDF

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf, mpdf

i installed mPDF 6.0 via zip file (not composer), put a font into the ttfonts folder and added the file in config_fonts.php like this:

```
"eurostyle" => array(   /* Custom */
    'R' => "eurostyle-normal.ttf"
    )
```

Now i tried adding the font to my mPDF object like this:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4-L');
$mpdf -> SetFont('eurostyle');
```

but nothing changes. There is no error message, the output PDF simpy stays the same.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your mPDF object without `c` as mode parameter. Use an empty string or eg. `UTF-8`.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('', 'A4-L');
```

`c` mode means the PDF will only use core PDF fonts - therefore it will not use any custom external fonts.

See also the [Fonts & Languages/Choosing a configuration](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/choosing-a-configuration-v6-x.html) page of the manual.