# How to generate PDF using mPDF and add custom Google font to it?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am generating PDF using mPDF PHP library. I am able to successfully generate it using the default font configuration. However, I want to render a Google font in my PDF. I tried using the steps mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317162/setting-a-custom-ttf-font-in-mpdf), but it did not work. Below is the code I use.

```
$mPDFO = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', 0, '', 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 'L');
```

Can anyone help me using Google Font in mPDF ?

Comment: I think you have to combine the steps in the question you provided and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739201/google-webfonts-in-pdf-generated-by-dompdf Download the fonts, convert them then include them. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in mPDF's documentation, it's not possible to use remote fonts directly by referencing them in the HTML. Follow the below steps to use custom fonts:

1. Download the fonts & upload them to mPDF's fonts directory `/ttfonts`
2. Declare the font-family you need to use in `config_fonts.php` under: `$this->fontdata`
3. Now comes the main part. You need to mention the font-family in the instance that you create to call mPDF's object which is what you missed, like so:

   `$mPDFO = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', 0, 'Source Sans Pro', 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 'L');`
4. Finally call the `SetFont` method like `$mPDFO->SetFont('Source Sans Pro');` just below your instance

Comment: Mind you, this works with any custom font that comes with a `.ttf` file. Doesn't have to be Google Font only.